# Regex, how to replace phrases / words not within anchor links?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm upgrading some code written in visual basic. The regex doesn't work as I'd expected.

Basically the regex is applied in a loop, it replaces keywords with anchor links. So it builds up a string which could have lots of phrases / words replaced with links to those phrases / words.

The problem is that if I have two phrases wiki and wikipedia. It will do wikipedia first as I've ordered the query to produce the list of phrases by length. However, the regex will replace wikiepedia then wiki reglardless of the whether wikipedia is converted to a link.

So I get a link within a link.

Heres the code.

```
do 
oRegExp.Pattern = "(" & title & ")(?![^<]*>|[^<]*</a>)"
title = " <a href=""view.asp?id=" guid & """>" & "$&" & "</a> "
content = oRegExp.Replace(content, title)
loop
```

Comment: I don't see how that could be happening, since you do have that negative lookahead that checks for following `</a>`, thus `wiki` in `wikipedia</a>` will simply not match when using that expression. Check what the exact string is when doing the `wiki` substitution. You can try adding surrounding `\b` around your title, like `"(\b" & title & "\b)`. Also I'd do this with one regex replace pass, using a hash table lookup in the replacement.

Comment: "(\b" & title & "\b) did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Adding part of my comment as answer as it seems to have solved it for you.*

You can try adding surrounding `\b` around your title, like `"(\b" & title & "\b)`.

When doing this you do not need to do the replacement in any specific order, as long as you are replacing singe words.